# javascript keep values after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, reload

I have a general question. I got a form made with django, if i use submit, but not all data is correct or when there are required fields missing, the page jumps back to default.
The values inside the form are saved but not the page lay-out.

my javascript that changes lay-out:

```
$(function(){
    $('li.fields').slice(1).hide();

    $('ul').on('click', 'li.title', function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle(200)
    })
});
```

short said, I would like to keep the status of the (un)collapsed fields. 
Could someone please point me in the right direction to achieve that (new to javascript)

Comment: use `ajax` to submit your form.

Comment: okay, i go take a look at that,  yet another part i need to learn. . haha

Comment: 1). You could 'ajaxify' (no refresh) the form. 2). Add validation to create a cookie or session from the valid data.

Comment: to clarify @JackWilliams comment: this is probably meant as either/or not both.

Comment: I have bene browsing a bit to find a nice "learn the basics of ajax" tutorial, but i only find short snipits, any suggestion for a good tutorial to learn this?

Comment: @Geert-Jan, is right, i should of clarified, thanks :-)

Comment: Mozilla tuts are almost always good (see for instance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) . Also always **avoid** w3schools. In case you don't know: ajax is not a jquery thingy. See the reffed mozilla tutorial for a barebones example without javascript. After that I recommend reading up on the jquery way, probably by reading: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ and it's related content

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use AJAX (or don't know how to use it), you can use a hidden field in your form.

[I've created a fiddle to simulate that](http://jsfiddle.net/SdWr5/).

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField" />
```

Updated Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('li.fields').slice(1).hide();

    $('ul').on('click', 'li.title', function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
        var myString = "[ "; // create a string to simulate an Array
        $('ul li.title').each(function() {
            myString += $(this).is(":visible").toString() + ", "; // iterate your list to take the visible values
        });
        myString += " ]"; // finishes the Array
        $("#myHiddenField").val(myString); // populate your hidden field
    })

    // when you get back from a submit, this hidden field will have some values
    if ($("#myHiddenField").val() != "") {
        var arr = eval($("#myHiddenField").val()); // turn the string into an Array
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // iterate the Array
            if (!arr[i])
                $("ul li.title").eq(i).hide(); // if the Array item is false, hide the respective li
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This was what I was going to recommend. Otherwise look into $.ajax() it's not too difficult as it use to be.

Comment: thanks, i will surely try this (tomorrow) and i think ajax is something usefull to learn anyway. but thanks alot!